# PyInstaller binary on Ubuntu does not run

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, pyinstaller

I am trying PyInstaller for the first time for a seperate Tkinter program

My OS-Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS Python-3.6.9 pyInstaller-4.2

the program is dependent on 2 other folders which have my code for some encryption(only key generation as of now) another for sqlite3 database handling.The file I wanted compressed is to setup the db and initialize a password and a key file so a GUI was made using Tkinter.

I used the following commands to create binary

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed Setup.py
pyinstaller --onefile Setup.py
pyinstaller Setup.py
```

I tried to run the binary file by

```
cd dist
./Setup
```

This results in no output